# SharePoint Workflow - Copy item to to a library which is not shared with anyone

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to find a way of copying a list item from a source library to destination, where the destination one is not shared with anyone apart from site admins.

So the scenario is following:

1. User uploads a file to a source document library he/she has
   access to.
2. Workflow of the source library is triggered copying
   the uploaded file to destination library, to which the user does not
   have access
3. The destination library triggers another workflow to
   perform particular check and sends notifications to site
   administrator

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: I'd be curious as to the business need for an inaccessible copy of content that exists on SP already.  One of the biggest benefits of SP is reducing the risk associated with numerous copies of content.   For the process portion of the question, you can create a workflow in SPD to achieve this.  Good luck!

Comment: Just reread your question; sounds like activating and using the Content Organizer feature would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however as we are using SP Foundation, the Content Organiser feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution for those who are having similar issue.

I created a workflow which performs all the required actions inside an Impersonation Step. This allows its content to run as workflow author (an admin) and copy (or perform any other action) without users having permissions to a particular source.